# How to Customize android share-intent

Tags: android, android-intent, rss

I have Created a little Rss Feed application. In this application I am fetching Rss in listview and if we click on any listview item it will open RssDetails.java activity which contains Rss detail description. In this activity i have implemented share intent in this activity.

RssDetails.java

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.details);
TextView detailsTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detailstitle);
TextView detailsDescription = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detailsdescription);
TextView detailsPubdate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detailspubdate);
TextView detailsLink = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detailslink);
 findViewById(R.id.sharebutton).setOnClickListener(this);

Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
detailsTitle.setText(bundle.getString("keyTitle"));
detailsDescription.setText(bundle.getString("keyDescription"));
detailsPubdate.setText(bundle.getString("keyPubdate"));
detailsLink.setText(bundle.getString("keyLink"));}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
if (v.getId()==R.id.button1) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
     intent.setType("text/plain");
     intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hello World");
     intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Share    via....play.google.com");
     startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share"));
      }
      }
```

Now i want that when i will click on share button the Rss Description should come instead of "Hello world". which should come from R.id.detailsdescription.

Answer (score 0):

Try addind like this..

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
if (v.getId()==R.id.button1) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
     intent.setType("text/plain");
     //intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hello World");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, detailsDescription.getText().toString());
     intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Share    via....play.google.com");
     startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share"));
      }
      }
```

Hope this helps..